No Normal Output of the Bump Node
I want to use the "Normal" or "Reflection" output from the Texture Coordinate Node. If I do so, the Bump node does not display any normal data. As You can see, the bump node should receive a black and White noise Texture:

However, the Bump node does not deliver a normal output:

If I set the Texture Coordinates to something different than "Reflection" or "Normal" the Bump node does deliver a normal output

(I think this is normal behaviour but if i only connect the Mapping node i get no Noise Texture, neither in the Normal nor in the black and white.)
I'm struggling to find my mistake. Is it that you simply can not use these outputs for a bump node? If so, are there any workarounds?
Settings:
| Render engine: Cycles
Specs:
Apple M1 Max
Using Metal GPU
Blender 4.1.1
